# Mid door knob installation door shut and can’t open

Tags: doors, stuck

I got as far as putting in anti-rotation block and screwing in latch when door was pushed closed and now I cannot open it up in order to complete the privacy door knob installation.  Luckily I was not inside the bathroom. But now door is stuck and I cannot open it back up to complete the install. Argh. [image]

Comment: Not sure why the down vote, reversed, you should accept your answer and that may help someone else that had the same and panicked a little to find the answer.

Comment: I have no clue what you are saying. This is first ever question posted so I don’t know what the hell I am doing. What even is a down vote?

Comment: Someone down voted your question with no explanation, this is why explaining the reason for a downvote is needed  I reverse these unless it is a really bad question (lots downvoting lately). Use the green check mark next to your answer that accepts the answer and will help others that search for the same.  These are explained in the tour. There are many here to help on just about anything DIY related for your home. Sometimes there is an answer in minutes sometimes days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind! Figured it out.  Add knob and turn...lol.  Well originally tried that and it wasn’t catching. Apparently I did not have spindle pushed all the way in tight and in place.

Comment: ...And if on the side without the doorknob & spindle, anything that will catch in the shaft recess will do in place of the correct spindle with a handle attached.